# EM Algorithm - Expectation w.r.t. a subset of current parameters

Tags: optimization, expectation-maximization, point-estimation

Suppose I want to make inference on a parameter vector $\theta $=$(\theta_{1},\theta_{2},\theta_{3})$ and I have some missing data $Y_{mis}$. I would like to use the EM algorithm to find the mode of the joint posterior $\pi (\theta_{1},\theta_{2},\theta_{3}|Y_{obs}) $ The EM algorithm would then dictate that given my current estimates of the params I can infer the distribution of $Y_{mis}$ in order to get an expected complete posterior. That is taking the expectation of the complete posterior w.r.t. $p(Y_{mis}|Y_{o},\theta_{1},\theta_{2},\theta_{3})$. However this conditional distribution is not available to me. $p(Y_{mis}|Y_{o},\theta_{2},\theta_{3})$ is, however, available and so I want to take the expectation step with respect to only a subset of the current learned parameters.

Is there any justification to this? Intuitively I am still learning about the missing data as I learn my parameters, but I cannot find any examples in the literature where the expectation is taken with respect to a subset of the current parameters.

Comment: Note that the EM algorithm relies on the inequality $\log\left(\int\right)\geq\int\log()$.  This would be a good place to start.